# smartface 4.4 appears developer information message after launch for ios app

Tags: smartface.io

For new version 4.4 of the smarface, although does not exist in the code, a message appears after lunch as "This app is created with smartface....". How to remove this message for Ios?

Answer (score 0):

For individual, commercial and enterprice users Smartface gives a custom splash support. If you have at least an individual licence, then this warning won't appear on your application.

But for the applications that are created with community licence, this warning will be seen on start.